# Is there a way to connect a Kafka connector container to remote confluent cluster?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have 2 VMs -

1. contains confluent cluster (which run by docker-compose)
2. kafka connect which run by docker container (image : confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.0.1)

I'm trying to link the connect container to the confluent cluster to add another connect to the cluster but it fails.

[image]

I'm running the cluster by the next docker-compose file :

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.0.1.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.0.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.0.1
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.0.1
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:7.0.1
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.0.1
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

and the **Kafka connect** by the next command:

```
    docker run -d \
  --name=connect \
  --net=host \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=REMOTE_IP:9092 \
  -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=803 \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart-avro" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-avro-config" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-avro-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-avro-status" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="http://REMOTE_IP:801" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="http://REMOTE_IP:801" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
  -e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `connect` service in the first Compose file that is connected to the "remote" broker container, so this should be enough.

To answer your question, though, you need to modify `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` to expose the remote IP of the VM that you've set in the `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`, and then you need to ensure that the VMs can communicate with each other through a network bridge.

Comment: If I want to create more than one worker (on different machines), is the container in the compose is enough?

Comment: You could always duplicate the same service in the same machine, if it has enough memory to do so. Overall, if you must use containers, using Confluent Kubernetes Operator would make more sense. Otherwise, using the Confluent Ansible playbooks are more suited for VM clusters.